# What is the distribution of a Cholesky transformed variable?

Tags: mathematical-statistics, data-transformation, simulation, cholesky-decomposition

I have a situation where I have a vector $\textbf{x} \sim N(\mu_x, \sigma^2_x)$ and a vector $\textbf{y} \sim N(\mu_y, \sigma^2_y)$. I want to generate a new $\textbf{y}_2$ that transforms $\textbf{y}$ to have a specific correlation with $\textbf{x}$. So I use Cholesky transformation to do so. But my question is, what is the distribution of  $\textbf{y}_2$ after this transformation?

EDIT: I am wondering what would be the mean and variance of $\textbf{y}_2$ in addition to whether it's still normal.

Here is my R code;

```
set.seed(100)

n = 10000

x_mu <- 0
x_sigma <- 2
y_mu <- 0
y_sigma <- 1

desired_cor <- 0.5

# x,y are independently distributed
x <- rnorm(n=n, mean=x_mu, sd=x_sigma)
y <- rnorm(n=n, mean=y_mu, sd=y_sigma)

# But I want to generate a new y that has r=`desired_cor`
# correlation with x 
C <- matrix(c(x_sigma, desired_cor, desired_cor, y_sigma),2,2)
U = chol(C)
d <- as.matrix(cbind(x, y))
d2 <- d%*%U

new_y <- d2[,2]

# This is about `desired_cor`
cor(x, new_y)
```

Comment: Gaussian distributions are (linearly) [stable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stable_distribution).

Comment: What would be the mean and sd of y2 though? Isn't that just saying y2 would be normal; I am also interested in the new mean and variance

Comment: I'm not fluent in R at all, so I'm not 100% sure I'm reading your code properly, but isn't $\mathbf y_2$ a linear transformation of $\mathbf y$ here ? If so, it is [well-known](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_normal_distribution#Affine_transformation), as @DifferentialCovariance said that if $\mathbf y_2 = A\mathbf y $ for some constant matrix $A$ then
$$\mathbf y_2 \sim \mathcal N(A\mu_y,A^T\sigma_y^2 A) $$

Comment: @StratosFair maybe I am misunderstanding here...what would be the constant matrix? U is not a constant matrix

Comment: $U$ *is* a constant. By definition, it is such that
$$U^TU = \left( {\begin{array}{*{20}c}
   1 & \rho  \\
   \rho  & 1  \\
\end{array}} \right) $$
Where $\rho$ is equal to `desired_cor`, so $U$ is not random.

Comment: Ah my bad, I remembered constant matrix as something with all the same entries. But it still would not help with variance of y2 though. Here, $\sigma^2_{y} = 1$ so then we have $A^T A$ , which collapses to what you just displayed. Shouldn't the variance be a scalar and not a matrix? Recall y and y2 are $n*1 $vectors. Or is this returning the covariance matrix in which case the answer is ${U^T U} _{2,2} = 1$

Comment: @StratosFair What would be the application here? I am having trouble seeing how to extract just the variance

Comment: What is a "Cholesky transformation"?

Comment: @whuber Best to find out from the OP what they mean, of course, but it could be [this](https://blogs.sas.com/content/iml/2012/02/08/use-the-cholesky-transformation-to-correlate-and-uncorrelate-variables.html).

Comment: Yes @DifferentialCovariance is correct. The trouble is, I am not sure what the transformed variable's shape and location is. And I need this information for a simulation.

Comment: @DifferentialCovariance One might suppose that's the case, but it hasn't even been assumed that $(\mathbf x, \mathbf y)$ has a multivariate Normal distribution, which would make it difficult to determine the distribution of any such *decomposition* of the variables.

Comment: @DifferentialCovariance 
Any solutions? I am still not sure what the variance would be

Comment: @asd As whuber suggested, we should consider whether $(\mathbf{x}, \mathbf{y})$ have a joint normal. If they do, then any linear transformations will have new scale parameters as StratosFair suggested. If we don't, then that joint distribution needs to be defined.

Comment: @asd Alternatively, look at the histograms, QQ plots and other approaches to examining if your resulting distribution is approximately normal. This might be fine if you are not trying to take further analytic steps but just want to know roughly what to expect from this decomposition procedure.

Comment: I am assuming they are joint normal. But I am not sure if their answer answered the question ... I don't see how that multiplication would result in the variance of new y